# How to differentiate between sending and receiving address in blockcypher api result?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

I am using BlockCypher's API to get a list of transactions for a bitcoin address. I need to maintain a record of **IN** and **OUT** transactions from this address with time and transaction hash. However, I am not able to differentiate between the receiving and sending address. It is so much clear with Etherscan.

**API Endpoint** :

```
https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/addrs/1rundZJCMJhUiWQNFS5uT3BvisBuLxkAp/full?confirmations=3&limit=2000
```

Can someone please help me differentiate it?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at

```
   "inputs": [
        {
          "prev_hash": "017ce1c080eda9c5364b6efbcbd2d9b790983bb36fb81316d53269bb83703f08",
          "output_index": 0,
          ...
          "output_value": 269570000,
          ...
          "addresses": [
            "1rundZJCMJhUiWQNFS5uT3BvisBuLxkAp"
          ],
          "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash",
          ...
        },
        {
          "prev_hash": "02be075b8e6cf357fd34f81eaa273e9e4f5f970af3dc01b9fa07ae0d1795cb75",
          "output_index": 1,
          ...
          "output_value": 3876180000,
          ...
          "addresses": [
            "1rundZJCMJhUiWQNFS5uT3BvisBuLxkAp"
          ],
          "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash",
          ...
        },
        ...],
        "outputs": [
        {
        "value": 47981690876,
        ...
        "spent_by": "fe6a1669bc5c00171b921d7883ff674a7ac3fb8cd6a986ef6c69175d336ffc89",
        "addresses": [
            "15Z9atbppxt97unmzBdGkHuSx9UdptwqDb"
        ],
        "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash"
        }
        ]
```

These are the relevant lines.